# Want to Display error messages in horizontal manner in primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

I am validating my form using backing bean and from there I am displaying error messages in an xhtml page using  the tag p:messages

```
![error messages displaying in vertical][1]
```

I am getting error messages in the bottom of the page.I have 20 error messages and they are displaying as

```
error 1

error 2

error 3

error 4

error 5

error 5

etc...
```

I want to display that messages in a horizontal manner like

error 1    error 2   error 3   error 4
 error 5   error 6
error 7    error 7   .
    .         .         .

How would I do this

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are unknown to me but I think that displaying different error messages on the same line is not the best approach. If you are displaying these messages as the result of validation consider using [PrimeFaces message](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/messages.jsf) component.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `escape='false'` on your p:message component.

From the primefaces documentation

> escape - Defines whether html would be escaped or not.

This would allow you to use html to format the message however you would like.